# Adding an additional value to a Convolutional Neural Network Input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of images I want to input to a Convolutional Neural Network Model, however, with each of these images, there is a range or distance from the object associated with the image.

I want to input this range as an additional piece of context for the CNN model.

Does providing this extra piece of information provide any benefit? Does it make sense to do? Is it feasible in Keras?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has been marked as too broad, unfortunately. I would suggest editing to specify what type of output you are trying to predict and adding a few lines of Keras code to illustrate what your network architecture currently looks like. This should make the question more specific.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a few options here, one is to encode your numerical value as a feature plane in your input. If your numerical value is `c` you can add a channel to each input image with the value `c` at every pixel.

Another option is to merge the value in as an additional input to the fully connected layer.

In keras this would look something like:

```
conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
conv.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
conv.add(Flatten())
conv.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

range_ = Sequential()
range_.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'))

merged = Concatenate([conv, range_])
merged.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

merged.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which option you choose will depend on your data and whether you think the numerical feature will help the convolutional layers better understand the input, or whether you think it's not needed until later. If you have time you can try both architectures and see which performs better.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, but how would I pass a Training Data such that Image (RBG) goes to Conv and Numeric data to Range

Comment: I think both of these ways will work but adding a channel with a c value at every point seems inefficient and a mild waste of parameters.  If you're using a 3x3 convolution you're 8 of the parameters are effectively redundant.  Is there a custom layer that could do this more efficiently?

Comment: Thank you, Imran. Does the method of adding it as an individual input to NN have a name? I am trying to find a paper providing some explanation/intuition about this method, to cite. Though It seems like there isn't much to work on.

Comment: @M.HosseinRahimi Perhaps "multiple input, multiple output" https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models