# Adding extra data to standard convolution neural network in pytorch

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to extra data during training Resnet18.
In my case it is gender information expressed as `gender=Tensor([g]), where g =[-1|0|1] for [female|unknown|male]`, and some shape descriptor obtained in previous steps, which is of the form `desc=Tensor([...]),  desc.shape = ([64,])`.
I followed the hints which i had found at [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818968/adding-an-additional-value-to-a-convolutional-neural-network-input/47819063#) and successfully added the gender information, however after i add the desc tensor, the Loss becomes NaN. I tried to normalize the resulting layer but to no avail. Here is the modified Resnet18 forward function that I use:

```
def forward(self, xy):
    x = xy[0] #torch.Size([4, 3, 224, 224])
    desc = xy[1] #torch.Size([4, 64])
    genders = xy[2] #torch.Size([1, 4])

    x = self.conv1(x) #torch.Size([4, 64, 112, 112])
    x = self.bn1(x) #torch.Size([4, 64, 112, 112])
    x = self.relu(x) # torch.Size([4, 64, 112, 112])
    x = self.maxpool(x) #torch.Size([4, 64, 56, 56])

    x = self.layer1(x) #torch.Size([4, 64, 56, 56])
    x = self.layer2(x) #torch.Size([4, 128, 28, 28])
    x = self.layer3(x) #torch.Size([4, 256, 14, 14])
    x = self.layer4(x) #torch.Size([4, 512, 7, 7])

    x = self.avgpool(x) #torch.Size([4, 512, 1, 1])
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1) #torch.Size([4, 512])
    x = self.fc(x) #torch.Size([4, 35]); torch.norm(x,dim=1) == tensor([4.4604, 1.9574, 2.0123, 1.9583])


    y = genders.transpose(1,0) #torch.Size([4, 1]);  torch.norm(y,dim=1) == tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.])
    desc = desc.type(torch.float32) #torch.Size([4, 64]); torch.norm(desc,dim=1) == tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.]

    z1 = torch.cat([x,y,desc],dim=1) #torch.Size([4, 100]); torch.norm(z1,dim=1) == tensor([3.6243, 2.5945, 3.1520, 3.0312])
    #z2 = self.bn2(z1)
    z1 = self.fc2(z1) #torch.Size([4, 35]); torch.norm(z1,dim=1) == tensor([1.2954, 0.9399, 1.0137, 1.1230]
    return z1
```

Would you know how to properly add the extra data to the layer?

Best

Chris

Comment: You should give us the dimensions for all the tensors. And try printing the norm (i.e. relative "magnitude") of the three things you are concatenating

Comment: hi, I added the norms and shapes of the tensors as comments. to my surprise the original computation of the resnet (x variable) is not normalized, those that i added are normalized